# Solving anagrams using math.

Tags: combinatorics

On Hacker Rank, there is Sherlock and Anagrams coding test.

The opening statement of the coding test is:

Two strings are anagrams of each other if the letters of one string can be rearranged to form the other string. Given a string, find the number of pairs of substrings of the string that are anagrams of each other.

There is this example:

kkkk

- There are 6 anagrams of the form [k,k] at positions [[0],[1]], [[0],[2]], [[0],[3]], [[1],[2]],[[1],[3]] and [[2],[3]]
- There are 3 anagrams of the form [kk,kk] at positions [[0,1],[1,2]],[[0,1],[2,3]] and [[1,2],[2,3]]
- There are 1 anagrams of the form of [kkk,kkk] at positions [[0,1,2],[1,2,3]]

Equally 10 anagrams.

Can this be solved with one or more mathematical equations?

From Googling around, I have found this reference that this is a simple combinatoric question with a known answer: binominal coefficient of $(n,2)$ which is $n(n-1)/2$.

I am not a mathematician so can someone tell me if it is possible please and show the maths equations involved?

Answer (score 1):

One way to think of this is to realize that in order for two substrings to be an anagram of each other, they must be the same length. Given a string of length $n$, the number of substrings of length $k$ is precisely $n-k+1$ as Phicar pointed out.

It would not be hard to write code to create a list of these substrings of a given length. You'd want to do this for all possible $k = 1,...,n-1$. For a fixed $k$, once you have the list of substrings of that length, you're looking for anagrams so order of the elements in the string no longer matters.

So you can sort the elements in each substring. Then all you care about it how many of those pairs are the same. To get all the anagram pairs you just need to select pairs of these sorted substrings that are the same. This gives you the factorial you mentioned. In general $\binom{n}{2}$ gives you the number of unique subsets of size $2$ from a set of size $n$, so it's exactly the number of pairs of elements in a set of size $n$. As an example consider

$aababa$

First we compile the list of all substrings of length $3$, there are $6-3+1 = 4$ such substrings.

$\{aab, aba,bab,aba\}$

Now you're looking for anagrams, so you can sort (by assigning each letter an arbitrary number, or order) each substring since order doesn't matter, to get

$\{aab,aab,abb,aab\}$

You can then sort this list

$\{aab,aab,aab,abb\}$.

This is now the key step that differs from your example. You now want to choose all the pairs from this list that are the same. In your example they were always the same, in this example the first three are the same, then the last is different. So the number of anagram pairs of length $3$ is $\binom{3}{2} + \binom{1}{2} = 3$.

You could write a program that would do this for a fixed $k$, then sum over $k = 1,...,n-1$ to get the final answer. No step of the code would be particularly demanding.

In the example you gave, every substring of the same length is an anagram of another substring of the same length. So if we follow the above process we for $k = 3$ we get

$\{kkk,kkk\}$.

You then want to choose all pairs that are the same, in your case this is always choosing all pairs from this set which is $\binom{4-3+1}{2} =1$. As you noticed. The above process is the generalization.

So in your case the number of anagram pairs is

$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \binom{n-k+1}{2}$.

Where $n$ is the number of copies of the same letter. Each summand amounts to the anagram pairs of length $k$. In general, a nice equation may not be possible because it will heavily depend on the word you start with. But some fun and not overly complicated code would produce a quick answer.

Answer (score 0):

The number of substrings of a string of the form $x^n=\underbrace{xxx\cdots xx}_{n\text{ times}}$ is $\binom{n+1}{2}$ cause essentially you are choosing inclusively(they can be the same, a substring of length $1$) the initial position and the end position of your substring. Now, every substring is an anagram of any other substring iff the length is the same, as you have noticed so it is not enough to take pairs in the space counted by $\binom{n+1}{2,}$ notice that the number of substrings of length $k$ is $n-k+1,$ just go left to right and you will see that. Here, we can take any other string, either itself but we can not repeat the pair, so we will have,notice that the plus one comes from choosing the same substring, $$\binom{n-k+1+1}{2}.$$
For example, if $k=1$ we will have $\binom{n+1}{2}=\binom{n}{2}+\binom{n}{1}$ which means take $2$ positions or the same position.(So, in your example, you are missing taking $([0],[0]),([1],[1]),\cdots$ )
The problem when the string is not of this form I suspect, requires some kind of careful recursion.DP?